# Python TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, typeerror, turtle-graphics

I'm new at this so bear with me, I keep getting the error `TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`. I'm not sure how to fix this error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()

bob = turtle.Turtle()
List = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "violet"]
List2 = [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]
C = (-1)
S = (9)

bob.speed(2)
bob.penup()
bob.left(90)
bob.forward(70)
bob.right(90)
bob.pendown()
def drawAnyShape(Side):
    for i in range(0,Side):
        bob.forward(50)
        bob.right(360/Side)

for i in range(3,9):
    S = (S-1)
    C = (C+1)
    bob.begin_fill()
    bob.color(List[C])
    drawAnyShape([S])
    bob.end_fill()

wn.mainloop()
```

Comment: `drawAnyShape([S])` You're calling it with a list, but then trying to use that list as an argument to `range`.

Comment: `drawAnyShape([S])` -> `def drawAnyShape(Side):`, Side is single element list, after that you pass it to `range(0,Side)`. `range(0, ['a', 'b', 'c'])` (or any other list) is not a correct invocation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()

bob = turtle.Turtle()
List = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "violet"]
List2 = [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]
C = (-1)
S = (9)

bob.speed(2)
bob.penup()
bob.left(90)
bob.forward(70)
bob.right(90)
bob.pendown()
def drawAnyShape(Side):
    for i in range(0,Side):
        bob.forward(50)
        bob.right(360/Side)

for i in range(3,9):
    S = (S-1)
    C = (C+1)
    bob.begin_fill()
    bob.color(List[C])
    drawAnyShape(S)  # <- problem is here!
    bob.end_fill()

wn.mainloop()
```

Comment: Will you explain what was wrong in the original code and what did you change to fix it?

Comment: As pointed out above you had `[S]` which is a singleton list with the value of S in it. In this version the variable `S` is passed in which is what is expected for `range(0, Side)` in the function `drawAnyShape`.